# Javascript, commonAncestorContainer has attribute with value

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure something out:

using this piece of code

```
window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer
```

in firebug i got response:

```
<a href="#" data-element="button" class="button" contenteditable="true">
```

So how can I find out if certain element contains attribute 'data-element' with value 'button'?

I tried using something like this:

```
if(window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer.hasAttribute('data-element === button')) {
        do something here...        

    }
```

but it does not work for me.

Comment: How about using CSS selectors (css[attr=value]) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: well, i need it in javascript not css.

Comment: well, try $("a[data-element=button]") in your console.